# Correct DC Adapter type to use for Arduino

Tags: arduino

What's the correct DC adapter to use with an Arduino?  Voltage, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find some documentation related to this on the Arduino Website here:
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove

Essentially.. the thing to know is that it is a 7805 regulator.. any excess voltage is being converted into heat.  The Arduino runs at 5V.. and in order for the regulator to work it needs to be a minimum of around 1.5 volts above that.. so your "Minimum" is about 6.5V DC.

You want to try be as close to that as possible - so 7.5 and 9 volts DC are fine .. you can run at 12 volts DC.. but the regulator will get a little warm.. and I wouldn't do this if you are powering much from the Arduino board as that will increase the heat output.

The bottom line: 7.5V DC is best, 9V and 12V DC are OK.  Anything about 12V is probably pushing it.  12V is the most common you will find "lying around".

The Arduino uses a Barrel-style connector .. it is compatible with most reasonably sized plugpacks.. I am not sure what the size in millimeters is.

Answer (score 4):

The spec sheets for the Arduino Duemilanove says it is a 2.1mm barrel jack, if anyone needs to know (See the Power heading):

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what Arduino you are talking about. The Uno has a barrel connector and recommends 7-12v. So any "Wall wart" with a center polarity positive connector that fits marked between 7v-12v should work fine. It's not clearly indicated but this is for "unregulated" and will be passed through an on board voltage regulator to turn it into 5v.

If you are using a Pro-mini or Lilypad then these require a **regulated** 5v. You can couple the aforementioned 7-12v wall wart with an LM7805 or equivalent regulator. Don't just hook a "5v" wall wart up to these platforms. They often put out in excess of 5.5v and the output can vary a lot.